# Smarty counter variable define in parent file but increment and using inside child includ file

Tags: php, smarty

I like to define a counter variable in parent tpl file (First.tpl) and increment and using it inside child include file (Second.tpl).

But the counter does not increase anymore.

First.tpl:

```
{assign var = "counter" value = 1 scope = "global"}
{foreach ...} //iterates at least 100 times
  {include file='Second.tpl'}
{/foreach}
```

Second.tpl:

```
{assign var="counter" value = $counter+1}
{$counter} //counter does not increase!

{if $counter > 10} do-something {/if} // if statement fails always!
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. What output do you expect?

Comment: To everybody: please think twice before click on 'close' button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I use to do something like that, increasing the value inside the loop, and passing the value to the included file. Try it:

**First.tpl**

```
{assign var="counter" value=0}
{foreach ...} /* iterates at least 100 times */
    {assign var="counter" value=$counter+1}
    {include file='Second.tpl' counter=$counter}
{/foreach}
```

**Second.tpl**

```
{$counter} /* Check if counter increase */

{if $counter > 10} do-something {/if}
```

**Note**.- I initialized `$counter` to zero.